# list indices must be integers or slices not str

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code like this,

```
def myfunction(json_dict):
     mylistsize = len((list(json_normalize(json_dict,'data')['title'])))-1
     print(mylistsize)
     data = [c for c in json_dict['data']][0]#This line when it is 0 or 1 or 2 works for me.
     df = pd.DataFrame()
     data_paragraphs = data['paragraphs']
```

But when I change it to include all the elements of my array, to something like this -

```
data = [c for c in json_dict['data']][0:mylistsize]
```

It gives me an error on this line -     `data_paragraphs = data['paragraphs']`

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: can you show the full traceback of the error?

Comment: data is a list not a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: What is `json_dict` and `json_normalize` function?

Comment: I answered, but the question shows little or no research. The error message, which contained the solution, was probably not even really read. It says the item was a list. If you think the item is a DataFrame or dict, your *very first* job is to investigate why you're getting the type that you're getting. Computers are really good at that. You, a human, are not. Ergo, your job is to find out what you have missed that the computer hasn't. `print(type(questionable_thing))` is your friend. As is `print(questionable_thing)`. Close in on the offending line with print statments. *Then* ask. Maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a list, from `data = [c for c in json_dict['data']][0:mylistsize]`. You access values in it like `data[0]`. To access json *inside* an item in the list, you do `data[0]['paragraphs']`.